# How to disable Joomla routing by Article ID with any alias but use exact alias only

Tags: sef, jroute, alias

Joomla use own SEF redirects what drives any variants of URL to same article basing on Article ID (no matter what alias will be used)

http://example.com/3-welcome-to-your-blog.html

or
http://example.com/3-welcome-to.html

or
http://example.com/3.html

all above drive at the same article.

My question - where is a part of code responsible for such a behaviour ?

Because I'd like to comment (disable) this part of code what is convenient feature sometimes, but in my case I need TO SAVE Joomla article IDs in URL - but Joomla should answers only to Article ID with EXACT alias

http://example.com/3-welcome-to-your-blog.html

all other "URL variations" like

http://example.com/3-welcome-to.html etc

should give natural 404 error.

I don't create a module or plugin, I just want to change default Joomla SEF routing to set "Article ID + exact alias only" if it's possible.

Thx in advance for any opinions or ideas to try (excluding idea "disable Article IDs through Admin settings" - as said above I need to save the ones)

Comment: Thank you for joining JSE and contributing.  Please take our [tour].  If you think users are misunderstanding your question, you may wish to [edit] it to improve the clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May not be practical for blog articles, but a fixed url can be achieved via menu items: https://docs.joomla.org/Search_Engine_Friendly_URLs#Limitations

Otherwise, if I see it correctly, you have to write your own plugin.
https://docs.joomla.org/Search_Engine_Friendly_URLs#Custom_Routing

Comment: Thx for pointing, but I don't think I need own plugin to OVERRIDE Joomla default behaviour, I just look is there a way to COMMENT/disable some lines in /components/com_content/router.php to allow only ID+exact alias...this case I suppose we remove some functionality, not override or add the one...may be my logic is wrong - this is why I've asked the question here to read some opinions.

Comment: Using a Plugin is how you can override core behaviour without editing the core files which is considered a no-no as your changes will get replaced when the core is updated. You may like to look at the `onAfterRoute` event as a place to start reading: https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/System